# How to structure subqueries/CTEs to replace nested aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, netezza

I am trying to find out what percent of the 'amt' values belongs to each of the 'percent' buckets.

Example Data:

```
amt | pct
5   | .5
10  | .6
15  |  1
20  | .8
```

Desired Results:

```
pctAMT | PCTrange
.3     | <65
.4     | 75-84
.3     | 100+
```

I've tried using a nested aggregate function, and also trying to use the total as a single value. However, I'm running into errors. I think I have to re-structure the query as a CTE or subquery but I'm not sure how.

```
SELECT SUM(amt)/(SUM(amt) OVER()) AS pctAMT,
CASE WHEN percent < .65 then '  <65'
            WHEN .65 <= percent AND percent <.75  then '65-74'
            WHEN .75 <= percent AND percent <.85  then '75-84'
            WHEN .85 <= percent AND percent <.95  then '85-94'
            WHEN .95 <= percent AND percent <1.00 then '95-99'
            WHEN .100 <= percent  then ' 100+'
        END PCTrange
FROM table
WHERE date = TO_DATE('2016-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY PCTrange
ORDER BY PCTrange;

ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  Attribute LN_HIST.LN_FNCL_RPTG_UPB must be GROUPed or used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your error looks like Netezza, so I added that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN percent < 0.65 then '  <65'
             WHEN percent < 0.75 then '65-74'
             WHEN percent < 0.85 then '75-84'
             WHEN percent < 0.95 then '85-94'
             WHEN percent < 1.00 then '95-99'
             ELSE ' 100+'
        END) as PCTrange,
       SUM(amt)/ SUM(SUM(amt)) OVER () AS pctAMT
FROM table
WHERE date = '2016-04-01'
GROUP BY PCTrange
ORDER BY PCTrange;
```

The important change is `SUM(SUM())` -- adding up the sums for division.

I also simplified the `CASE` expression.  The clauses are evaluated in order, so you can take advantage of that.  The date comparison is also simpler.